# the server _ip_ at __ requires a username and password

Tags: php, tomcat, alfresco

Am setting up a php site in the alfresco's bundled tomcat.
using the war from http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/.

when i load up the in a browser the page partially loads and i get the 
popup asking for username and password "the server _ ip_ at __ requires a username and password"

i have not setup any authentication, and the page fails to load on clicking cancel.

how should i remove the popup

edit : am using windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename the .htaccess file to something else [or delete it at your own rist but it may break the script]

Comment: thanks @ 0xAli but there is no .htaccess file ? , also, i was changing the site and it worked, if i put in to a sub folder not directly in to webapps. if i move the site to webapps/folder/site works with out a problem. But i dont know why it happens

Comment: Then search for WWW-Authenticate in the PHP code

[ref http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php ]